# Share to Instagram Feed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

On this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed) there is a very handy introduction to allowing your apps users to be able to share their content from your app directly into their Instagram feed. Currently it seems like this is only offered to Android and IOS applications (going by the page linked). I am wondering if anyone has been able to do this using Javascript instead or if it is even possible at this stage?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instagram does **not** support sharing functionality for the **web** at this point. You can find very well documented sharing capabilities for [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web), but since Instagram's API does not allow web sharing I'm afraid there is no way for a workaround. The only way to share on Instagram is through a native app, but you are already aware of that.. good luck!